# Storing dynamic values in a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I Have values of 4 variables which are dynamically updated,I wanted to store these values in a column in dataframe whenever they are generated

```
ef['quantity']=self._quantity
ef['avg_price']=self._avgprice
ef['pnl']=self._pnl
ef['amount']=self._bookvalue
```

Only the last generated values of the variables are stored into the specifiy columns ,how to append the previous values generated by each variable

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are talking about.  You really should provide a [mcve] to reduce ambiguity.  But I'll take a guess at what you mean.  Keep a dataframe with a multi-level index in which the first level is a time stamp and the second level is whatever you're currently durring.  Each time you produce something to add, do `ef = ef.append(pd.concat({pd.Timestamp('now'): ef_with_new_vals}))`.  Then you keep track of all of the past values and you can do more tricks down the road.

Comment: If you want more details, edit your question to make it better and I'll be happy to follow up.  Don't try to clarify in the comments.  That won't be enough.  When you've updated your question, feel free to reply to me.